# Is it convenient for me as a freelancer to ask for Amazon gift cards as payments?

Tags: payments

In my country, which is Venezuela, it is somewhat complex to get money from outside, so one of the best options is Amazon and its gift cards. Is it feasible for me to ask for payment in that format instead?

Comment: Will you use Amazon gift cards to pay your bills or buy your food? Can you transform them in cash?

Comment: He can resell them, he can buy goods online for himself or resell them, etc. There's great value in Amazon and other gift cards.

Comment: Always **READ THE TERMS OF SERVICE** for gift cards. Gift cards expire, have limitation or restrictions, etc.... cash doesn't.

Comment: Check for Payoneer card for Venezuela. You can get money to it and withdraw from the ATM and it's very hard to be tracked down.

Comment: go-me: I think is a bad idea to be payd with gift cards. If I urgently need to pay my bills and I have $1000 in gifts cards, If I can't resell them to anyone then I could not pay anything. Also why one would buy a $100 amazon gift card if he can directly spend $100 on amazon itself? It's a waste of time and you also loose a %. I 100% prefer cash unless you can convert a gift card in cash like in an ATM or so.

Comment: @Mario If Lenin CANNOT get more than $3000/year with online payment, he can still offer his services without being limited by this. Sometimes, the option is $3000, and not more. Gift cards can be useful to people who don't have a credit card, and can be resold 100% of their value. Some simply resell gift cards for a less; if he's happy with this, that's a personal choice! Of course if he can get "real" online money, it's better. I pointed out already the inconveniences when being paid in gift cards and that's the question. But being in Venezuela limits the options! Cash by mail isn't safe.

Comment: The main reason people look for options like Amazon is you can transform money quickly into stuff you can get in the country without the trouble of getting direct $ cash.. Not just for resell which would be a lesser option in most cases.

Comment: Also I wasn't looking about paying people outside the country, but getting paid from outside in a way which doesn't require U.S. Bank accounts to do so.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking about the convenience for companies in the United States of America some may have issues with sending gift cards for fear of possible IRS ramifications. I had once asked a similar question and that was the response I had received.

It would also depend on the size of the company you work for. You are more likely to get paid in gift cards if the business is sole proprietor or small group.

Although still in its infancy, and depending on its legal status in your country, Bitcoin or other digital currency may be an option. Imho, nothing compares to the ease and quickness which it can transfer wealth.

Either way It doesn't (shouldn't) hurt to ask. Unless of course it may be perceived as a tax dodge of some sort.

Comment: +1 You're right that some companies could be worried with IRS, it complicates their accounting for sure. Never used Bitcoin, and not too sure how it works but might be a good option indeed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and yeah I was asking about that exactly.! I think Bitcoin is the future for every online transaction but as a new standard is still in development. ;) let's be optimistic #babysteps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can ask for this. Maybe some will find it a bit unusual but it could work. A lot of companies buy these cards to give as corporate gifts and have piles of them. I think these cards are also easily available in stores and groceries or online.

**The issues I could see with this is:**

1) You get sent cards that were already used on Amazon. But you can always verify this when you get them.

2) It's a bit like being paid in cheque/money order... so ideally you would need to wait until you get the cards before sending your final files (if there are final files in your field of work.) As you guess this could make some clients a bit impatient/worried. You'll need to think of a system to not end up working for free and to also make the client trust you; they might not all understand the reason why you ask for this.

---

I guess you already explored you other options but I'll add this in case you didn't.

Money order? That could be safe.

Western Union should work but the fees are usually quite high.

Apparently it's possible to use Paypal but the administrative process from your country can take a few months and the amount you can get on the account is limited. But maybe you could combine this method and other methods.

There's Visa gift cards that are like prepaid credit cards and can be activated safely.

[Something to read here about all this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140717014939-65520575-five-alternative-ways-to-get-paid-from-venezuela).

Comment: Thanks for your recomendations, I think I would look into these Visa gift cards.. Also about the alternatives on the bottom link, I wonder why always those articles look from the perspective that native Venezuelans have a need to pay outside individual or corporation and not focus in all the people here who want to get paid from outside without excessive trouble.

Comment: Still be careful with the gift cards, I guess once they're filled up with the money, it's all yours but some could be like "prepaid cards", and the person sending it to you could also take the money out of it. Again, have fun reading terms ;)  Regarding the url, maybe they want to be politically correct and not encourage citizens to try to "bypass" the country's laws. It's often written from an american perspective but the issue for you (and the lack of online payment options) is caused by the control on how the money gets in the country. Not an easy situation for citizens.